# ¿Existe algún lenguaje de programación que soporte la programación aritmética multidígito?

Tags: python-2.7, octave

Quiero hacer operaciones (suma, resta, multiplicación, división, raíz cuadrada, ...) con números de hasta 100.000 dígitos. La mayoría de los lenguajes de programación manejan números hasta 10^50 aproximadamente, que está muy lejos de 10^100000, que es lo que yo quiero usar.

Quiero preguntaros si algun@ conoce la programación aritmética multidígito y cómo orientar el programa. La Programación aritmética multidígito consiste en que cada dígito está en el rango de 0 a 32767 (por ejemplo) y permite manejar números mucho más grandes que los dados de serie por los lenguajes de programación.

Comment: Hola Javier, te invito a que hagas el recorrido de bienvenida para que entiendas cómo funciona el sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y de paso ganes tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 3):

Hasta donde sé

**Python:**

Python no tiene limite en el rango de los números enteros que quieras manejar (aparte de la memoria que tienes que tener para poder manejar datos tan grandes).

**Java:**

Java los soporta *out-of-the-box* usando la clase [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

**C/C++:**

En C o C++ puedes usar la librería [GMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multiple_Precision_Arithmetic_Library)

- [Enlace a la página oficial de la librería](https://gmplib.org)

Answer (score 0):

Lo he comprobado en Python y sí maneja números de muchísimos dígitos (he probado casi 9000 dígitos)